# Spellchecker for windows forms in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am looking for a third party component that could handle spellchecking for Windows forms (.Net 2.0 or .NET 3.5) I have the following requirement:

1. The component should be able to use Open office dictionary (Need to use a Swedish dic I think the OO is the best one)
2. Be able to underline in the UI while typing, like word. (Don’t want to implement this by myself)
3. Be able to underline in a simple textbox not just rich textbox. (Don’t want to change to much in the legacy code)
4. Be able to use customized dictionary so I can use both the OO dictionary and my own textfiles with words at the same time.

I have found a spellchecker that do all this things and that is [XtraSpellchecker](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Spell_Checker/) from Devexpress the only problem is that its not spelling correctly for some words with Swedish OO-dictionary . Its not the OO dictionary that is the problem because the dictionary work fine with NHunspell.

I may fix this small bug if I buy the component with source from devexpress but its hard to convince management to buy something that they don’t know if it will work or not.  I have asked on devexpress forum if it’s a bug but waiting for response.

There is one “maybe” requirement also and that’s management probably want to have a spellchecker for WPF too and its always good if I can get both WPF/Win Form from the same vendor. I can not use the built in spellchecker in WPF because there is no Swedish dictionary.

Anyone know any other spellchecker component that meets my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

This might help, if the users will have word installed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203681(office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I want to exclude word if its possible. One of the problem I see with word is that you need to implement the underlining by yourself in the simple textboxes.

Comment: a co-worker sent this to me, you might want to check it out. . . .http://www.karamasoft.com/whitepapers/Free-Spell-Checker.pdf

Comment: They have now implemented Hunspellchecking in http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Spell_Checker/ 

Before that where my workaround using the DevExpress UI for spellchecking and connecting NHunspell to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [netspell](http://www.aspcode.net/Use-NetSpell-in-your-ASPNET-20-application.aspx) not sure if its EXACTLy what you want, but its pretty good.